# Importing links+anchors from URL into 1 row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import up to 3 links and their anchors from a given URL and have those in 1 row in the following fashion:

| link 1 | *anchor 1* | link 2 | *anchor 2* | link 3 | *anchor 3*

So far, I've accomplished this:

## 1st row:

| link 1 | *empty column* | link 2 | *empty column* | link 3 | *empty column* |

using:

```
=SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",,",TRUE,ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(H5,"//a[contains(@href, '"&$E$1&"')]/@href"),3,1)),",",TRUE,FALSE)
```

## 2nd row:

| *empty column* | anchor 1 | *empty column* | anchor 2 | *empty column* | anchor 3 |

using:

```
=SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",,",TRUE,array_constrain(importxml(H5,"//a[contains(@href, '"&$E$1&"')][1]"),3,1)),",",TRUE,FALSE)
```

H5 here contains the URL to import from and E1 is the domain only for which links should be imported, as shown in the [dummy spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RhrNHwmTKvPXvShJzR0clfZ9-pVd6DBUlD7nhtKM8yY/edit#gid=0).

I really need to use only 1 row to get the desired result.

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet, and include in it an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Hi! While generating a dummy spreadsheet for the demo - I've succeeded to accomplish the first part of what I wanted. Nevertheless - I still don't know how to combine the anchors for the links. I will edit the question. The dummy ss: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RhrNHwmTKvPXvShJzR0clfZ9-pVd6DBUlD7nhtKM8yY/edit#gid=9310183

Comment: This has not been completely solved. Please see 1st comment on first answer and exp5 on the dummy spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RhrNHwmTKvPXvShJzR0clfZ9-pVd6DBUlD7nhtKM8yY/edit#gid=9310183&range=H16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved anchor issue for links in the same paragraph as follows:

```
=SPLIT(ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(",",ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(H5,"/html/body//a[contains(@href,'"&$E$1&"')][position()<4]"),3,1)&","&ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(H5,"/html/body//a[contains(@href,'"&$E$1&"')]/@href"),3,1))),",")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
=split(arrayformula(join(",",ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(H5,"/html/body//a[contains(@href,'"&$E$1&"')]/@href"),3,1)&","&ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(H5,"/html/body//a[contains(@href,'"&$E$1&"')]/text()"),3,1))),",")
```

---

The trick is to first join the two constrained arrays using `&","&`. The `arrayformula` + `join` makes sure that first for each row, the elements are joined. And then all the rows are joined.

Finally, you split them and they come out neatly.

To get a better sense of how this works, see the output of:

```
=arrayformula(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(H5,"/html/body//a[contains(@href,'"&$E$1&"')]/@href"),3,1)&","&ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(H5,"/html/body//a[contains(@href,'"&$E$1&"')]/text()"),3,1))
```

PS: This formula uses `/text()` instead of `[1]` for fetching the anchors.

Comment: Hi, I have been using this for a while and found a glitch - In cases where 2 urls are imported, if theyare under the same paragraph (i.e. between same <p>...</p>) - the first anchor will be imported twice for the 2 different links. I couldn't find a way to resolve it, so removed the "V" as the solution is not complete. Do you have an idea of how to do it? Thanks!